# How to upload Video to youtube using api and form application asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using **you tube api** i want to upload video from my web application how can i do it?
I also want to trace the uploading progress so i can show the progress to the users..
Is there any solutiuon please help me to get out it...

I have tried the below method

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("appname", "mykey", "username", "password");
                YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
                Video newVideo = new Video();
                newVideo.Title = "Test";
                newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
                newVideo.Description = "Testing Testing Testing";
                newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
                newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("C:\\22.flv", "video/mp4");
                Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

in this method there is no option to check the uploading progress so how can i do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441553/youtube-c-sharp-net-api-uploading-video-and-getting-events-when-finished

Comment: any one please help me to get out of it... :(